# TypeScript: dynamic typing on fields in a class using generics and chaining

Tags: typescript

I am trying to build a class, and it has a field `model` that can be extended according to which plugins have been registered on the class.

I try to use conditional types to give the field some type hints so users can use it easily: I want the type of `service.models` change on every `.use()` call.

I have the following, but it is never working, and also getting error like: `Type 'Service<Models>' is not assignable to type 'NewService extends Service<infer NewModels extends ModelBase> ? Service<NewModels & Models> : this'.`

```js
export type MaybePromise<T> = T | Promise<T>

type ModelBase = Record<string, string>

export interface ModelList {
  models(): MaybePromise<Record<string, string>>
}

class ModelListImpl implements ModelList {
  models() {
    return {
      model_1: 'model-1',
      model_2: 'model-2',
    }
  }
}

class Service<Models extends ModelBase = Record<string, never>> {
  models: Models = {} as Models

  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  use<NewService extends Service<any> = this>(service: ModelList): NewService extends Service<infer NewModels> ? Service<NewModels & Models> : this {
    const models = service.models()

    const newModels = {
      ...this.models,
      ...models
    }
    this.models = newModels

    return this
  }
}

let service = new Service()
service = service.use(new ModelListImpl())

// this should be typed {model_1: ..., model_2: ...}
service.models
```

Comment: I started working on this and things look really muddled with your `MaybePromise`.  Where in the code are you checking whether values are promises and acting accordingly?  Everything here seems to assume there are no promises, just plain objects.  Either `Service<M>.models` should be of type `MaybePromise<M>`, or `use()` will have to return a `MaybePromise<Service<??>>`, since there's no way to magically turn a `Promise<T>` into a `T`.  How would you like to proceed here?

Comment: (see prev comment) I expect something like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nn5bqw) might work for you, but I had to put in a bit of effort to maintain the presumed "if neither of these are promises then the result is not a promise" constraint.  Is that what you're looking for?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! That was my fault, `models()` should be either a async function that returns a `Promise` or a sync function. I forgot to make my `models()` to be async in the demo code. Yeah, I have solved that issue with your implementation! Thanks again! And I do want to know if I can solve this with conditional types!

Comment: ① So, should I write up my answer? ② I don't understand why you'd want to use conditional types here; they are not necessary for anything in the example code.  It's like asking "I want to go to the 2nd floor of a building; I know there's an elevator, but can I solve this with a rocket instead?" The answer is "probably, but you really shouldn't."

Comment: 1. Yes please!
2. True. I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A major problem with the implementation of your example code is that the `models` property of `Service` is a `MaybePromise`, and the `models()` method of `ModelList` also returns a `MaybePromise`, so the code

```
const newModels = {
  ...this.models, // MaybePromise
  ...models // MaybePromise
}
```

has a very good chance of trying to use object spread on at least one `Promise`, which is not going to work.  If either one is a `Promise` then you need to write some asynchronous logic to combine them into a new `Promise`.  One way to do that looks like

```
const oldModels = this.models;
const newModels = (("then" in models) || ("then" in oldModels)) ?
    (async () => ({ ...(await oldModels), ...(await models) }))() :
    { ...oldModels, ...models, };
```

where if either `oldModels` or `models` are a `Promise` (determined by the presence of a `"then"` property), we return an [immediately-executed `async` function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE#execute_an_async_function), in which the pieces to spread are `await`ed.

Do note well that once you have asynchronous code, order of operations becomes harder to reason about.  It is very important that we use a new variable `oldModels` instead of just `this.models`, because if you assign `this.models = newModels` inside the function, then by the time the `async` code actually runs, `this.models` will quite likely point to `newModels` and then you'll have a `Promise` waiting for itself.

Anyway, now that the implementation will work at runtime, we should get the types right.

---

Here's one approach:

```
interface ModelList<T extends ModelBase> {
    models(): MaybePromise<T>
}

class Service<M extends ModelBase = {}> {
    models: MaybePromise<M> = {} as M

    use<L extends ModelBase>(service: ModelList<L>): Service<L & M> {
        const models = service.models();
        const oldModels = this.models;
        const newModels: MaybePromise<L & M> =
            (("then" in models) || ("then" in oldModels)) ?
                (async () => ({ ...(await oldModels), ...(await models) }))() :
                { ...oldModels, ...models, };
        this.models = newModels;
        return this as Service<M> as Service<L & M>;
    }
}
```

I've added a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter to `ModelList` so that it knows about the return type of `models()`.  Then, inside `Service<M>` (I'm using the short `M` instead of `Models` for the type parameter), `use()` accepts a `ModelList<L>` (I'm using the short `L`, for `ModelList`, instead of `NewService` for the type parameter).  Then `use()` returns a `Service<L & M>`, combining both the new service models type and the old one.

You need a few [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), especially because we're mutating `this` instead of returning a new `Service`, and TypeScript can't easily represent such mutations at the type level.  Oh and also note that I'm using `{}` instead of `Record<string, never>`, since we want to say that the default model has no *known* elements, not *no elements at all forever*.

---

Okay, let's test it out:

```
let service = new Service();
//  ^? let service: Service<{}>

class ModelListImpl {
    models() {
        return {
            model_1: 'model-1',
            model_2: 'model-2',
        }
    }
}

let service2 = service.use(new ModelListImpl()) 
//  ^? let service2: Service<{ model_1: string; model_2: string; }>
```

Note that I created a new `service2` variable instead of reusing `service`.  The type of `service` is always and forever `Service<{}>`. Again, TypeScript doesn't represent mutations at the type level, so even if you assign the result of `use()` to `service`, the type of `service` will not change to reflect that.  It's therefore better to use a new variable.

Okay, let's consume `service2.models`, which needs to be written to handle a `MaybePromise`:

```
if ("then" in service2.models) {
    service2.models.then(v => 
      console.log("was a promise", v.model_1.toUpperCase()));
} else {
    console.log("was not a promise", service2.models.model_1.toUpperCase());
}
// "was not a promise",  "MODEL-1"
```

Looks good. The compiler understands that `model_1` exists on either directly `service2.models` or the resolved value of the promise.  Because neither the original `service.models` nor `ModelList`'s `models` return type is a promise, then `service2.models` is also not a promise.

Now let's see what happens when we provide a `ModelList` that actually returns a `Promise` for `models()`:

```
const sleep = (ms: number) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, ms));

let service3 = service2.use({ async models() { 
//  ^? let service3: Service<{ model_3: string; } & { model_1: string; model_2: string; }>
  await sleep(1000); return { model_3: "model-3" } } });

if ("then" in service3.models) {
    service3.models.then(v => console.log("was a promise",
      v.model_1.toUpperCase(), v.model_3.toUpperCase()));
} else {
    console.log("was not a promise", 
      service3.models.model_1.toUpperCase(), service3.models.model_3.toUpperCase());
}
// "was a promise",  "MODEL-1",  "MODEL-3"
```

Now `service3` is a `Service<{ model_3: string } & { model_1: string; model_2: string }>`, and when we check `service3.models`, we see (after one second) that it is a promise that eventually resolves to a `{ model_3: string } & { model_1: string; model_2: string }`, as expected.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAsgQzAIygBQE4HsC2BLAZygB4AVAPhgF4ZSYAfGTXQki4USWOLAEygA2AIQRFqMAEpQAxlgy9iBEBjwA7AOYAaGEpUbyHNSCgYAZgmnc+ggDKEQZGFAAex1bwLxrw0VEoBvYBhgmBxvAgAKAEoALngkVGZ8IjIDAF9gaQFRTwBlEwA3PEtiOCdXKHdPHn4fMRp-NICgkLDagjjEFHRsZJI4Sga0mFF4DhCYAFcUm3K3Dy9akSJyCKIMIstO7zslYhtyWJh8jeKSWYAyeGaJidlVJVDw8XXNqAA6NsFIqIBuFtuMHujywAl4NW+4hAAAtCJ9wv9AcFgSAYKooAB3CECDrxbpJVj7GBXAbUAFI4IRCIAIhhlWpMDUT3aUQYjBpdNUDKZoPB4SirIA-OSKRMIqIwKppDBotRKBF-DB3srxRiEHhUbzsQQotple9VerUV8cay0gLZTERaLgor9VrwnrlSaCNo0oikTC4S7xOisQjrcEMFAQJMMKoYF7PKMTm9SpQY4UzkSSeQPcEMhlgAIQzok5ZfZjjvmoNF-gB6cvBAB6gpgOdRrzOcVjycaBky2QI1R29gAkjgIAIYIEJi7ZaOkcHQ+GR4HbiaAPoARjiAHITQBaZdrzTzsfeRcAJnXW6Pu-nGQmmY4Dbzp0sR5eJfe01LfsWtn7g4E0VZlZgYhN03GAwCwSYgQQVQ11RYM3xGGACgQFQEGQHMYAxDVoXA1EBCwAg1HUSNIEI4AAJgWt61zJtHxbEtiEVJdVx0ZRCN+ZlBGPOJdDYmAmkMUwZVpaF6UZCMaKgI94RZOcJgkqSXXeTkInnAo5SBLAHlBD48PUGk1WjGAIF6VhqW0AppM45clKwABVCBoAwABhXw-z+YBhm+WBJ2RTSCG095dP00ZVCwVEECMkyiDM+83gU8JLIEFcbPsxyXKIP9-gyADqQMtEwoQ4yWGi7QYGpOAAHkABEAFEbG3BkOBRHQcygCBxAiHBcVUSYcFQDBWSoSgPwJDKIgG9SiBAUg8BwKAcPG7QuoFf5s2oksAGZnwfSTXwywJyNrckJSlDicQnecEDVDUWqgNqImXAAGZ6-hgacwwjRjDw2uJqS3DaGSvEJM3cjhgDwQSORErkxNis4NsSnVZJCCSEcU5TVPU4EAqC3LRgioq+hiiymJShyTHS0tdUQxLFwRkA7PJ5zXIFdzPJxbzyWxnNAqwPS8c8ULwsi4qoBi1HEdp6yGdSimWe0CXFKXenGbSlm2bIqsBcKqKxdK8rqrqhr9cq2r6oBmBgCAA)